# Cookies to redirect to 2 possible secondary pages on website

Tags: php, cookies

I was wondering if someone can assist pretty please. So I'm busy building a website. On first visit to the home landing page a user must choose between 2 call to action buttons. Based on their choice they are either directed to content on /page1.php or to the content on /page2.php.

Now I don't wan't the user to constantly go back to the home page every time they visit the website and have to choose again between these 2 choices. I assume I need to add some sort of cookie to the home page to redirect users to either /page1.php or /page2.php (based on their initial choice.)

Any and all help as to how to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of `page1.php` and `page2.php` you can set a cookie to say that the user has been on that page.

```
setcookie('landing_page_reached', 'page1');
```

Then at the top of the first landing page, have something like this:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['landing_page_reached']) && in_array($_COOKIE['landing_page_reached'], array('page1', 'page2'))) {
    header("Location: /{$_COOKIE['landing_page_reached']}.php");
    die;
}
```

Notice the whitelist array I created... you do not want people to people able to set custom content in headers!

Comment: Thank you kindly! I'll give that a try and let you know if I don't come right x

Comment: Be sure to let mark the answer as correct if it is what you're looking for!

Comment: nah it doesn't seem to make a difference I keep going back to first landing page after adding the script. Maybe I'm putting it in the wrong place? (I put it above the <!Doctype HTML> )

Comment: I assume you are putting it within PHP tags? You can also check your developer tools in your browser to see if the cookie is being set correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I think there may be something on the secondary pages which is preventing the Cookie from executing. Will do some more homework. Thanks again. :)